# How to disable a shell keyword?

Tags: bash, command-line

Using `enable` builtin command we can disable a shell builtin command, for example `echo`, as follow:

```
enable -n echo
```

But how can we disable a shell keyword like `time`? If we try:

```
enable -n time
```

we will get the following "answer":

```
bash: enable: time: not a shell builtin
```

**Note**: I know how to [run the `time`](https://askubuntu.com/q/434289/147044) that's in `/usr/bin`, so I just want to know if it is possible to accomplish what I asked in the title.

Comment: Anything you truly want to accomplish why you want to disable the `time` keyword?

Comment: @konsolebox `time` it was just an example.  If you type `help` in your terminal using bash you can find out that `A star (*) next to a name means that the command is disabled`. That's what I want to accomplish.

Comment: I would guess that disabling a shell keyword is actually a means to some other end. What are you trying to accomplish by disabling a keyword?

Comment: @DougO'Neal Let say that disabling a shell keyword allows you to execute a disk command which has the same name as a shell keyword without using a full pathname or an alias.

Answer (score 6):

You can do:

```
alias time='"time" '
```

(the trailing space is to allow alias expansion after it, as a bonus).

Quoting a keyword (keywords being part of the shell language syntax) stops it from being interpreted as a keyword, so here, normal command look up is performed on it.

It works in `bash`, `zsh`, `mksh`, but not `ksh93`, `ash` or `yash`.

Note that for non-interactive `bash` instances (like in scripts), you need `shopt -s expand_aliases`, as contrary to other shells, `bash` doesn't expand aliases by default when not interactive.

Comment: You didn't read my note from my question (or you didn't understood it). If you type `help` in your terminal using bash you can find out that `A star (*) next to a name means that the command is disabled.` That's what I want to accomplish.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu, then `help() { builtin help "$@" | sed 's/ time /*time /'; }`

Comment: I repeat: *If you type `help` in your terminal using bash you can find out that `A star (*) next to a name means that the command is disabled`. That's what I want to accomplish.* If this is not possible, then show some resources why...

Comment: @RaduRădeanu It is not possible to mark a keyword as disabled in bash because the notion of marking as disabled applies only to builtins, not to keywords. It is possible to disable a keyword, as in making the word not be a keyword anymore, and Stéphane has showed you how.

Comment: Hmmm. POSIX states that “reserved words in correct grammatical context shall not be candidates for alias substitution”, which is a bit odd considering that alias expansion substitution “before applying the grammatical rules” and before recognizing reserved words. It looks like the spec was written specifically to accommodate some odd behavior from ksh.

Answer (score 2):

As you found out, you can't *disable* a keyword with `enable -n`.

However, you can make a keyword a builtin also with `enable -f` and then disable it:

- unpack the sources for your current version of `bash`
- `./configure && make`
- In `examples/loadables`, you'll find a number of example loadable builtins, edit one of them, for instance the `sync` one to replace all instances of `sync` with `time`.
- run `make` in `examples/loadables`.
- In `bash`, run `enable -f ./sync time`.
- `enable -n time` now works. And `help` shows: `*time` (in addition to `time [-p] pipeline`)

(not that it's ever going to be useful to anyone).

Comment: Nice try and I admit that I was fooled until to check step by step your answer :). But the new created shell builtin `time` will not replace the shell keyword `time` and, the most important, will never work as you described (bash [will crash](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HhEJD.jpg) immedialy after the new created builtin is runned). In the end `enable -n time` will work for new created builtin, but not for the shell keyword as I asked. So, in fact, your answer doesn't have nothing to do with my question.

Comment: @Radu, Yes, as I said in [the initial version of the answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/148498/1) (before somebody edited that away), _stupid answer to a stupid question_. If you want to disable the keyword, see [my other answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148492/22565).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than disabling the keyword, if you can call it without the shell's parser finding it in *command position* - or the first word in a simple command - you should be able to run it without trouble. The POSIX-specified command `command` is designed to do just that. So you can, for instance, call a command called `time` like:

```
command time
```

This works in any shell as far as I can tell. It is strange, though, that many seem to handle it differently. Here's a demo:

```
echo 'echo "$0"' >./time
chmod +x ./time
for sh in dash ksh zsh bash yash 'busybox ash' posh mksh
do  command -p $sh -c '
    PATH=.:$PATH
    printf "\n%s\n" "$0"
    time
    command time' "$sh"
done
```

#### OUTPUT

```
dash
./time
./time

ksh
user    0m0.00s
sys     0m0.00s
time

zsh
shell  0.00s user 0.00s system 71% cpu 0.005 total
children  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 0.005 total
time

bash

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
./time

yash
./time
./time

busybox ash
./time
./time

posh
./time
./time

mksh
    0m0.00s user     0m0.00s system
./time
```

Answer (score 0):

In zsh you can disable reserved keywords with the `-r` flag.

Answer (score -2):

You can't disable it but you can hide it with a function. Use at own risk.

```
shell_builtin() {
    :  ## Do nothing.
}
```

To enable it back, simply unset it:

```
unset shell_builtin
```

Comment: The OP want to disable shell keyword, not builtin.

Comment: @Gnouc Then it's not possible.

Comment: You can use `complete -r commandname`.  to remove a certain command from autocompletion.

Comment: @holasz I was quite hasty answering it. `time` is a special keyword that's probably on the level of `if`, `while`, `case`, etc. that's why you can't disable it.